# FPC connector for 0.75 mm pitch

Tags: breakout, ribbon-cable

Got an OLED module with a FPC ribbon that has pitch 0.75mm. How do I prototype with a breadboard? I can only find breakout boards for a pitch of 0.5mm. Not only that, how do I prototype with a PCB, when I can't even find connectors for 0.75 mm.

Any idea how I can use this module?

Answer (score 1):

0.75mm is an odd value. I've used several FFC/FPC connectors from [JST](http://www.jst.com/home20.html) in the past, and they have a wide offering starting from 0.2mm, most of them 0.5mm and 1mm. None with a 0.75mm pitch however. I would **contact the manufacturer** of the OLED module for information where they get their connectors.

Answer (score 1):

Is the FPC for hotbar soldering or for use with a connector?
I use this kind of adapter for display testing: http://www.newhavendisplay.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1107
[image]

It has a 0.75mm pitch (and many others) and you solder the FPC tab to it. You can find it on Digi-Key and probably all the rest as well.

Comment: It's really for prototyping, so I would prefer a connector. Though it looks like I'm going to have to solder since I can't find the correct pitch connector anywhere.

Comment: Thanks!.. I will use this adapter for LCD zebra to PCB connection. I avoid to make a board.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this seller on AliExpress that sells a 1.69" LCD TFT display and it has a 12pin 0.75 pitch strip pin. here's the [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002761126978.html?gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt). I've sent a message to him to inquire for such a FFC 0.5mm pitch connector. In the meantime, link is above for anyone do the same.